# How to run Test dependsOnGroups, with maven command

Tags: java, maven, testng

I want to execute run test, my code looks like:

```java
public class TestClass{

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestClass.class);

 @Test (groups = "tOne", dependsOnGroups = "tTwo")
 public void testOne(){
  LOGGER.info("tOne execute");
 }


 @Test (groups = "tTwo")
 public void testTwo(){
  LOGGER.info("tTwo execute");
 }

}
```

My command line in maven : `mvn clean test -Dgroups=tOne -Denvironment=qa -Dbrowser=chrome`

My command line it is ok?

After execute maven print this: `depends on nonexistent group "tTwo"`

(-environment and -browser not relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with command line :
`mvn clean test -Dgroups=tTwo,tOne -Denvironment=qa -Dbrowser=chrome`